# Junit test not passing. New to unit testing services

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Writing a unit test for my Spring Boot service method and I cannot get it to pass. I am a front end developer so I am not very familiar with unit testing in Java. The multipartFile is what is confusing me the most, as well as completing the entire Junit test.

Junit4 with mockito unit test. Tried stackoverflow and google for potential corrections.

Contract Service

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class ContractService {

    @Autowired
    public ContractRepository contractRepository;

    @Autowired
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public UserSettingsService userSettingsService;

    @Autowired
    public ContractPermissionsService contractPermissionsService;

    @Autowired
    public OCRSubmissionService ocrSubmissionService;

    @Autowired
    public ContractDocumentStorageService contractDocumentStorageService;

    public Contract getContract(int contractID) {
       Contract contract = contractRepository.getOne(contractID);
       return contract;
    }

    //TODO: come back and reduce contractID / metaID to one ID.
    //TODO: add trigger in DB layer for coterminous
    // TODO: make sure isVisible defaults to false

    /*
    When adding a new contract, the following steps are taken:
    1. SQL transaction is begun
    2. The meta information is stored, and an ID is generated in SQL.
    3. The file is stored with the corresponding document ID.
    4. The meta information is updated with the document link.
    5. A login, submission, and logoff are made to KTA.
    6. As long as all these steps have completed, the transaction is completed
    7. Otherwise, the transaction is cancelled ad an error is thrown (controller returns 500)
     */
    @Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
    public Contract addNewContract(Contract contract, MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
        Contract newContract = this.contractRepository.save(contract);
        int ID = contract.getId();
        int fileID = this.contractDocumentStorageService.storeFile(file, ID);
        contract.setDocumentPathDesc(Integer.toString(fileID));
        this.addViewingPermissionsForSubmitter(contract);
        Boolean success = this.ocrSubmissionService.SubmitContractForOCR(file, contract.getId());
        if(success) {
            return this.contractRepository.saveAndFlush(newContract);
        } else {
            throw new OCRSubmissionFailureException("Error in OCR Submission");
        }
    }
```

Contract Service Test

```
public class ContractServiceTest {

    ContractService contractServiceUnderTest;


    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        contractServiceUnderTest = new ContractService();
        contractServiceUnderTest.contractRepository = mock(ContractRepository.class);
        contractServiceUnderTest.jdbcTemplate = mock(JdbcTemplate.class);
        contractServiceUnderTest.userSettingsService = mock(UserSettingsService.class);
        contractServiceUnderTest.contractPermissionsService = mock(ContractPermissionsService.class);
        contractServiceUnderTest.ocrSubmissionService = mock(OCRSubmissionService.class);
        contractServiceUnderTest.contractDocumentStorageService = mock(ContractDocumentStorageService.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddNewContract() throws Exception {
        // Setup
        final Contract contract = new Contract();
        final MultipartFile file = null;
        final Contract expectedResult = null;

        // Run the test
        final Contract result = contractServiceUnderTest.addNewContract(contract, file);

        // Verify the results
        assertEquals(expectedResult, result);
    }
```

Comment: It means you have a Contract with the contractID of `0`. I'm not sure what the problem is. Try to delete the contract which has the ID 0 and report back

Comment: Devy, I had the wrong test method linked. The testAddNewContract() method is the one I added.

Comment: I just read your commend for Enzo, so this is working fine now?

Comment: It is not. Enzo posted the earlier method. I edited for a new test method.

Comment: Is the exception thrown when you run the test case? And have you checked if the database entry is actually made at `        Contract newContract = this.contractRepository.save(contract);` After the initial run of the test, can you please check if the entry is subsequently removed because of using @Transaction & expected exception to be thrown here `        int fileID = this.contractDocumentStorageService.storeFile(file, ID);` Another thing, at this method `contractDocumentStorageService`, do you have a check if `null` is sent as its parameter, throw an exception?